# Check request headers in an S3 static site

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, web-hosting, cloudflare, request-headers

I am hosting a website on an S3 bucket using the static website functionality.

In between the client and the website there is CloudFlare.

I have enabled a CFlare functionality that adds some custom headers to the requests reaching the S3.

Is there a way to check if these headers do reach my website?

Comment: What would it matter? Your website cannot do anything based on the headers anyway.

Comment: just to check if they do arrive

Comment: I'm not sure but you can try Logging requests using AWS s3 server access logging, it might capture the headers as well.

Comment: I have enabled server access logging and checked; the request headers are not logged there.

Comment: Yes, because S3 simply does not log all headers, does not tell you anything about the headers being present or not.